# Prevent Button from firing when enter or space is pressed Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I have a button on a Scene, that whenever the space bar or enter key is pressed, this button automatically fires. I want the user to be able to type  these keys without this button firing. I have already tried doing `root.requestFocus()` and calling the request focus method on other nodes in my scene. How can I prevent this button from firing when these keys are pressed. Thanks for any help.

Edit:
So far I have just done the boiler plate code to make a Javafx application work, added that button and a few labels. I have tried the requestFocus() method in several nodes in my application, none of which has made a difference. I also have a `scene.setOnKeyPressed` action event listener for keys pressed.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding an event filter for `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent` that [consumes the event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--)?

Comment: Could you include code. I want this button still to be accessible when the user clicks on it.

Comment: @Jack `button.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, Event::consume)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `button.setFocusTraversable()` method ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusTraversableProperty)). This prevents the button from being focused automatically, e.g. by pressing *TAB*.

```
Button button = new Button("Some Action");
button.setFocusTraversable(false);
button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Some action called!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your `defaultFocusNode` has focus, and you don't want your `button` to do its default behavior of taking focus for itself (and away from `defaultFocusNode`) when `button` is clicked. When `button` gets focus, this code will immediately give focus back to `defaultFocusNode`.

```
button.focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue)  defaultFocusNode.requestFocus();
      });
```